# RDP Connection Issues

Tags: remote-desktop

Question 1

I set up RDP on Windows 10 PRO as well as an Android Tablet.

I can access the host computer from the Tablet if I am on the same network but not if the host and tablet are on different networks.

Both networks have internet connections and are connected.

Question 2.

I set up RDP Wrapper for multiple simultaneous connections to the host. I ran the Configuration program and everything is GREEN. Everything looks good. However, if I try to connect a second user to the Host, the user already on the host is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: RDP is a machine-to-machine protocol, so requires direct "line-of-sight" between the two machines. If the machines are on different networks, then there is no direct line of sight. You could use a VPN tunnel or a similar device to "bridge" the two networks.

Q2: Yes, this is by design. Windows clients only support 1 actively logged on user, Windows Server normally supports 2 and if you want more, you probably need Remote Desktop Services (and a license server).